# Parse directory name from a full filepath in C#

Tags: c#, file

If I have a string variable that has:

```
"C:\temp\temp2\foo\bar.txt"
```

and I want to get

**"foo"**

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use:

```
new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\temp2\foo\bar.txt").Directory.Name
```

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx the FileInfo constructor can throw if the caller does not have the required permission. Is there an alternative that will only parse the string without any IO ?

Comment: @GuiSim: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: In case someone needs the full directory path, use `new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\temp2\foo\bar.txt").DirectoryName` instead.

Comment: String manipulation:
var dir= _installPath.Split(new[]{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();

Comment: I'm convinced that Google has some top secret Stack Overflow infiltration department and Jon Skeet is one of their highly trained operatives. There's no other way someone working at a demanding company like Google has this much free time to answer questions.

Answer (score 11):

Far be it for me to disagree with the Skeet, but I've always used

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\temp\temp2\foo\bar.txt")
```

I suspect that FileInfo actually touches the file system to get it's info, where as I'd expect that GetFileNameWithoutExtension is only string operations - so performance of one over the other might be better.

Comment: There's a slight difference in results here... I think your approach returns "bar" when the question is asking how to get "foo" the file's containing directory...

Comment: I learned two things today... Read the question and never disagree with the Skeet.

Comment: Doesn't Path.getDirectoryName do exactly what he wants?

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName would return "C:\temp\temp2\foo"

Comment: You could do `Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath))` - which in testing appears to do the job, and doesn't touch the filesystem.

Answer (score 8):

I think most simple solution is

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

string folderName= dinfo.Parent.Name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on Handleman's suggestion, you can do:

```
Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
```

This doesn't touch the filesystem (unlike `FileInfo`), and will do what's required. This will work with folders because, as the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> **Return value:** The characters after the last directory character in path. If the last
>   character of path is a directory or volume separator character, this
>   method returns String.Empty. If path is null, this method returns
>   null.

Also, looking at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,95facc58d06cadd0) confirms that `GetFilename` doesn't care if the path passed in is a file or a folder: it's just doing pure string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I had an occasion when I was looping through parent child directories

```
string[] years = Directory.GetDirectories(ROOT);
foreach (var year in years)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(year);
    Console.WriteLine(info.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(year);
    //Month directories
    string[] months = Directory.GetDirectories(year);
    foreach (var month in months)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(month);
        //Day directories
        string[] days = Directory.GetDirectories(month);
        foreach (var day in days)
        {
            //checkes the files in the days
            Console.WriteLine(day);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(day);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);                               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using this line I was able to get only the current directory name

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(year);
Console.WriteLine(info.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend on how you want to handle the data, but another option is to use String.Split.

```
string myStr = @"C:\foo\bar.txt";
string[] paths = myStr.Split('\\');
string dir = paths[paths.Length - 2]; //returns "foo"
```

This doesn't check for an array out of bounds exception, but you get the idea.

Comment: That will fail on Linux.

Comment: Path.DirectorySeparatorChar